# CAST diagrams with tanθ and an infinite denominator?

Tags: trigonometry

I am given this equation to solve for $\theta$ :

$$\tan2\theta = 3\cot\theta$$

And I am given the following answer:

$$\tan\theta = \pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\\
\text{or denominator} = \infty\\
\theta = 37.8°, 218°, 142°, 322°, 90°, 270°$$

What does it mean by denominator = $\infty$, and where did $90°$ or $270°$ come from?

**Edit:**
This is the full working out
[image]

Comment: See now, please. I posted a right reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\theta = 90°, 270°$ then $\tan\theta = \infty$, this implies that the denominator is $\infty$ on line 4 of the calculations. Which also implies that the equation itself is satisfied (because the numerator is of order $\tan^3\theta$ and numerator only of order $\tan^2\theta$).

Comment: Oh, thanks! The remaining question is how from $tan\theta = \pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ is $\text{denominator} = \infty$ obtained?

Comment: These two solutions are independent. Or you make the denominator $\infty$ or you make the numerator $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't still understand where $\text{denominator} = \infty$ comes from. Is there something special about the question asked that allows for the denominator to be infinite or the numerator to be 0?

Comment: No, thats just the solution to the equation. There are two possibilities: or the numerator on line 4 is 0, or the denominator is $\infty$. There are no other ways to make the fraction equal to 0.

Comment: Ah, I finally get it. I'm guessing that by multiplying the denominator on line 4 to get rid of it and to let only the numerator remain, I am losing a solution?

Comment: Exactly. But its easy to make that little mistake.

Comment: @NDewolf $\infty$ is not number. You can not say that "denominator = $\infty$".

Comment: Yes i do realize that. But i just wanted to keep the answer simple. I could have said that the denominator diverged to $\infty$ so that the fraction converged to 0, but this would not have made the solution any more useful.

Comment: @NDewolf I understood, what you wish to say, but I think it's better to give reasoning without words "denominator = $\infty$" or the the similar things.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning. I only intended to explain why the person who asked the question received that result in the first place. But your reasoning is indeed more formal.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of given equation is $\{\theta|\cos{2\theta}\sin{\theta}\neq0\}$.

We need to solve $$\frac{\sin2\theta}{\cos2\theta}=\frac{3\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$ or
$$2\sin^2\theta\cos\theta-3\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)=0$$ or
$$\cos\theta(2-2\cos^2\theta-6\cos^2\theta+3)=0,$$ which gives
$\cos\theta=0$, which is $\theta=90^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$\cos^2\theta=\frac{5}{8},$$ which is
$$\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{8}{5}$$ or
$$1+\tan^2\theta=\frac{8}{5}$$ or your
$$\tan\theta=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$

Comment: I didn't think of it this way. But this makes things clearer as well, thanks. Could you explain what $k\in\mathbb Z$ means in this case? I don't understand that notation.

Comment: @Kyzen It just says that $k$ is an integer number.